# What climbing vines will cover a 40' high cliff in southern Spain?

Tags: plant-recommendations, vines

We live in southern Spain, and have the problem of trying to disguise a massive cliff wall behind the house. We intend to erect large metal fencing to the cliff, which is 100 feet long by 40 feet high!

Our question is what vines to use to cover as much of it quickly. We have to use containers, because the cliff is made of reinforced concrete, and the pots for the vines need to be placed 12 inches away from the cliff's base. Also we will be away from June till October, so we must plan a watering system. We're thinking of something along the lines of Morning Glory, as this would have green leaves all year, to try to hide as much of the cliff as possible.

Comment: A cliff is rock, so this sounds more like a wall.

Answer (score 3):

You've a problem if you can only plant in pots. Any large vine or climbing plant so contained will only ever achieve a few feet, say 6 feet if you're lucky in 2 foot deep pots, because of the constriction to its root room, so this does not sound like a good solution to your problem. If you can find somewhere to plant into soil, and then train towards the cliff, that might work.